# How to get other claims from Keycloak AuthzClient

Tags: java, keycloak

I'm using AuthzClient to obtain a access token using the following code:

```
Map<String,Object> clientCredentials = new HashMap<>();
clientCredentials.put("secret", keycloakClientSecret);

Configuration configuration = new Configuration(
        keycloakUrl, keycloakRealmName, keycloakClientId, clientCredentials, null
);

AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create(configuration);
AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = authzClient.obtainAccessToken(
        loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()
);

System.out.println(accessTokenResponse.getOtherClaims());
```

I'm getting the access token and refresh token successfully but I can't get the other claims. It's empty.

I've configured Mapper to include my custom attribute from portal. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I didnt find any solution about keycloak authzclient. But i am using jwt decode solution as https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt

my example like this with jwt-decoder:

```
public Claim getClaimByName(String key)
    {
        try {
            DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(this.tokenResponse.getAccessToken()); // just token as String
            return jwt.getClaim(key);
        } catch (JWTCreationException exception){
         return null;
        }
    }
getClaimByName("site").asString()
```

Comment: I'm also doing this. Can you please complete the code? For example, where to find the key?

Comment: Key is pre-defined attribute value. im defined user attributes tab on realm users page. My      codes are so distributed inside project. which exactly do you want?